# TapJoy Rewarded Videos ads not showing

Tags: java, android, kotlin, tapjoy

I'm trying to implement Tapjoy Rewarded Videos into my app, however they're not showing up.

```
private var directPlayPlacement: TJPlacement? = null
private var TJlistener: TJPlacementListener? = null
```

Here's my initTapJoy() function:

```
  fun initTapJoy() {
    val connectFlags: Hashtable<String, Any> = Hashtable<String, Any>()
    connectFlags[TapjoyConnectFlag.ENABLE_LOGGING] = "true";
    connectFlags[TapjoyConnectFlag.USER_ID] = AppPreferences.token;

    val callbackTJ = object : TJConnectListener {
        override fun onConnectSuccess() {
            this.tapJoyConnectSuccess()
            Timber.d(TAG, "TapJoy SDK connected");
        }

        override fun onConnectFailure() {
            Timber.d(TAG, "TapJoy SDK not connected");
        }

        fun tapJoyConnectSuccess() {
            Tapjoy.setActivity(activity);
            Tapjoy.setUserID(AppPreferences.token);

            directPlayPlacement = Tapjoy.getPlacement("RewardedVideo", TJlistener)

            TJlistener = object : TJPlacementListener  {
                override fun onRequestSuccess(p0: TJPlacement?) {
                    if (p0 != null) {
                        Timber.i("Tapjoy on request success, contentAvailable: %s", p0.isContentAvailable)
                    } else {
                        initTapJoy()
                    }
                }

                override fun onRequestFailure(p0: TJPlacement?, p1: TJError?) {
                    //activity.toast(getString(R.string.adds_content_empty))
                    Log.d(TAG,"onRequestFailure")
                }

                override fun onContentReady(p0: TJPlacement?) {}

                override fun onContentShow(p0: TJPlacement?) {}

                override fun onContentDismiss(p0: TJPlacement?) {
                    initTapJoy()
                }

                override fun onPurchaseRequest(p0: TJPlacement?, p1: TJActionRequest?, p2: String?) {}

                override fun onRewardRequest(p0: TJPlacement?, p1: TJActionRequest?, p2: String?, p3: Int) { }

                override fun onClick(p0: TJPlacement?) {
                    if (p0 != null) {
                        TapjoyLog.i(TAG, "onClick for direct play placement " + p0.getName())
                    }
                }

            }

            directPlayPlacement?.videoListener = object: TJPlacementVideoListener {
                override fun onVideoStart(p0: TJPlacement?) {}

                override fun onVideoError(p0: TJPlacement?, p1: String?) {
                    activity.toast(getString(R.string.adds_content_empty))
                }

                override fun onVideoComplete(p0: TJPlacement?) {
                    getReward(4)
                }

            }

            //load ad
            if (directPlayPlacement != null) {
                directPlayPlacement!!.requestContent();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Tapjoy SDK must finish connecting before requesting content.")
            }


        }
    }

    Tapjoy.connect(activity, API_KEY, connectFlags, callbackTJ);

    Tapjoy.setDebugEnabled(true);

}
```

And this is the showTapjoyRewardedVideo() function:

```
private fun showTapJoyRewardedVideo() {
        if (directPlayPlacement == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Tapjoy: Direct Play placement is null. No direct play video to show")
        }
        if (directPlayPlacement?.isContentAvailable!!) {
            if (directPlayPlacement!!.isContentReady) {
                directPlayPlacement!!.showContent();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Tapjoy: Video not ready to show")
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Tapjoy: No video to show")
        }

    }
```

LogCat:
http://prntscr.com/udhl8e

Please note that I've added my device as a Test device, they're still not showing up, plus I asked people from different countries to open rewarded videos, as I thought they don't have videos available for my country, didn't work.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that using the above code, another default Placement called AppLaunch was showing up as a modal, meaning that the integration worked, however it doesn't work for the rewarded videos.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to get my currency approved by TapJoy, there was nothing wrong in my code.

Comment: Hi, do you remember for how long did you wait for that approval?